# Calculate number of time between Time In and Time Out using php

Tags: php

I have Time In and Time out of the users daily.

Example data:

Time In: 7:00 AM (emp_in)

Time out: 5:00 PM (emp_out)

What I am trying to do is just count the number of time between 8:00 AM to 5:00 PM since the user only scheduled for 8:00am to 5:00pm Only

Here's the sample code that I am playing with.

```
$result_in_out = strtotime($emp_in) - strtotime($emp_out);
$result_hours = abs(floor($result_in_out/3600));
$Considered_Hours = $result_hours;
```

I still can't find and formulate a good logic to interpret my desired output programmatically thanks

Comment: what is the problem? and what is your desired output?

Comment: the code calculates the 7:00am to 5:00pm but what I'm trying to do is only 8:00am to 5:00pm

Comment: if the user is scheduled from 8:00 AM ,can you clarify why emp_in , is from 7:00 AM, if i am right did you simply mean to add +1 hour to 7:00 AM?.

Comment: There are some instances that some users did their time in at 7:00AM but the code should start counting the times at exactly 8:00am only since they are scheduled at 8:00am

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you should find the difference between `Time IN` entered and `8:00 am` and then add the difference time to the Time IN `$emp_in` and then `subtract` the `time out` from `time in` to get your desired output.

```
$emp_in = '7:00 am';
// find the difference between time entered and 8:00 am
$diff = '8:00 am' -$emp_in;

// multiply the diffrence time to 3600 to change to second and then add with time in
$emp_in = strtotime($emp_in) + ($diff*3600);

$emp_out = '5:00 pm';

$emp_out = strtotime($emp_out);

$result_in_out = $emp_in - $emp_out;
$result_hours = abs(floor($result_in_out/3600));
echo $result_hours;
```

Comment: what If the users did their time in at 6:00AM does this code will still starts to count at 8AM?

Comment: No, but let me customize for every possible time in

Comment: I'm thinking that if else should be implemented in this kind of situation but idk how to do it with this kind of problem.

Comment: @KingRG the answer is updated let me know if your problem is not solved.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it works for you <3

```
    $time1 = '07:00:00';
    $time2 = '05:00:00';
    $array1 = explode(':', $time1);
    $array2 = explode(':', $time2);

    $minutes1 = ($array1[0] * 60.0 + $array1[1]);
    $minutes2 = ($array2[0] * 60.0 + $array2[1]);

    echo $diff = $minutes1 - $minutes2.' Minutes';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$datetime1 = new DateTime('11:00 AM');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('01:00 PM');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%hh %im');
```

PHP help doc : [Click Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)